# How to render XSL based on conditional statement

Tags: html, xslt, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need help with syntax

From a CMS I'm getting some title information (Music, TV, Comedy) Now I need to run a check in xsl to see which one comes up and then render the appropriate content (in my case a set of checkboxes)

Based on what Title comes up I want to render different XSL code. If Title = TV then show this XSL, else if Title = Music then render this XSL instead.

This is my code so far, however it's *throwing an error* because I have an XSL when statement inside of an XSL if statement.

```
<xsl:template name="PrintTitles">             
<xsl:param name="ids"/>
<xsl:if test="$ids">

    <xsl:variable name="itm_id" select="substring-before($ids, '|')"/>

    <!-- xsl:if -->
    <xsl:if test="$itm_id">

        <!-- Variable item & title -->
        <xsl:variable name="itm" select="sc:item($itm_id,.)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="sc:fld('Title', $itm)"/>
        <div class="related-genre-types-{position()}" style="display:none;"><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Title', $itm)"/></div>

        <div class="music-choices" style="display:block;">

            <!-- Displays title -->
            <div class="choices-title"><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Title', $itm)"/></div>
            <div class="choices-checkboxes">

                <!-- where I try to use the 'when conditional' throws error because this is inside of <xsl:if test="$itm_id">-->
                <!-- if title = TV then render this -->
                <xsl:when test="title = TV">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$TVGenres/item">
                        <div class="category_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="getf{sc:fld('@id',.)}" name="getfItem" value="{sc:fld('title',.)}" />
                            <label for="get{sc:fld('@id',.)}"><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /></label>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- if title = Music then render this -->
                <xsl:when test="title = Music">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$MusicGenres/item">
                        <div class="category_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="getf{sc:fld('@id',.)}" name="getfItem" value="{sc:fld('title',.)}" />
                            <label for="get{sc:fld('@id',.)}"><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /></label>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- if title = Comedy then render this -->
                <xsl:when test="title = Comedy">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$ComedyGenres/item">
                        <div class="category_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="getf{sc:fld('@id',.)}" name="getfItem" value="{sc:fld('title',.)}" />
                            <label for="get{sc:fld('@id',.)}"><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /></label>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="PrintTitles">
        <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-after($ids, '|')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:if>
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: This is what happens when one messes up with conditional logic. Strongly recommend *not* to use explicit conditional XSLT instructions. You can greatly simplify the transformation by using a set of template -- one for each of the conditions. No tangles, everything short and clear.

Comment: Thanks, any chance for a link to what that would look like? You mean a PrintTitles template for each choice?

Comment: Leon, I would like this question and show what I mean. The reason I am not doing so is that the question, in its current forms, is severely underspecified: where is the source XML document? Where is the wanted result? Without these you cannot expect anyone to "show" you techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:when>`s have to be inside an `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="...">
     ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="...">
     ...
  </xsl:when>
  ...
</xsl:choose>
```

Also, your conditional statements like `title = Music` should actually be `title = 'Music'` if you want to check whether the `title` element has the value "Music", etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting an error anymore, but my when the condition is met the html inside of the appropriate xsl:when does not show up. How would you run a test for this? Like console.log for xsl?

Comment: Thanks, you helped me fix my error so checking this as answer, I'll write a new question up if need be